# Using rsync to copy files from one server to another, pertaining users and permissions

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, file-permissions, permissions

I'm backing up user uploaded files from my primary server to my failover server using `rsync`.

If I use `rsync -a` to mirror an `/uploads` directory from server `A` to server `B`, can I expect programs using the files in `/uploads` on server `B` (e.g., Nginx, etc.) to function like it did on server `A`, assuming I've created users with the same names and permissions on server `B`, or will I run into subtle problems later that I may have just overlooked? So, is copying a directory of files with preserved ownership and permissions interoperable amongst similar machines, or will it copy ownership via UID and therefore screw everything up when I happen to create users in a different order, etc.? Are there other considerations when doing this, or do you have any recommendations on a better way to handle this sort of backing up with `rsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, this will work as expected, but `-a` won't copy extended attributes (`-X`), ACLs (`-A`) and hard links (`-H`), so if your files use these, add these parameters.

One note: Permissions will be copied based on numerical UID and GID and not an a text name. If these don't match on the target server, you obviously might face problems.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is there a common pattern that's used to prevent problems like this, such as manually assigning numeric IDs to users upon creation, or something else? I would hate for this to accidentally work just because I happened to create the users in the same order or something to that effect.

Comment: The common pattern for this is to create a central user database (like LDAP) when you have many servers with users that need to be the same.

Comment: Small correction: Usernames and Groups are mapped based on the names unless you use --numeric-ids

Comment: @fukawi2 - excellent, thanks! SvW - thank you, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two paths to follow.
First, you should create users and groups with the same UID and GID in both servers, so that you have no surprises later on.
Second, once the rsync is done, you should really access the backup server in every way that main server is accessed: try httpd, mail, files, etc and check if it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that, at least for initial testing purposes.